# Postfix master.lock: permission denied

Tags: 12.04, permissions, postfix, lock

I'm triyng setup the postfix, but with no success.

I am using webmin to configure.

my problem is that postfix won't start, always with the same message:

```
Mar 19 19:21:13 site postfix/postfix-script[1247]: starting the Postfix mail system
Mar 19 19:21:13 site postfix/master[1248]: fatal: open lock file /var/lib/postfix/master.lock: cannot open file: Permission denied
Mar 19 19:21:14 site postfix/postfix-script[1318]: warning: group or other writable: /var/lib/postfix
Mar 19 19:21:14 site postfix/postfix-script[1325]: warning: not set-gid or not owner+group+world executable: /usr/sbin/postqueue
Mar 19 19:21:14 site postfix/postfix-script[1326]: warning: not set-gid or not owner+group+world executable: /usr/sbin/postdrop
Mar 19 19:21:14 site postfix/postqueue[1357]: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly
```

I'm going crazy with this... really! I don't know more what to do...I already tried to create the file master.lock, set permission, delete file, reboot server...

See the permissions:

```
drwx-wx--- 2 postfix postdrop 4096 Mar 19 18:04 /var/spool/postfix/maildrop
drwx--s--- 2 postfix postdrop 4096 Mar 19 17:54 /var/spool/postfix/public
drwx------ 2 postfix root 4096 Mar 19 17:54 /var/spool/postfix/private
-rwxrwS--- 1 root postdrop 13624 Feb 20 23:38 /usr/sbin/postdrop
-rwxrws--- 1 root postdrop 13608 Feb 20 23:38 /usr/sbin/postqueue
drwxrws--- 2 postfix   postdrop 4096 Mar 19 19:11 var/lib/postfix
```

It seems, obviously, its a permission problem, but I don't know how to fix it...

I have spent about 4 hours researching and triyng all I've found... but with success

thanks

Comment: While I cannot help you with that issue, I want to advise you to go a different route, don't use webmin - it is not compatible with Ubuntu/debian and follow [The Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/email-services.html) to configure your mail server.

Comment: ok, i will try to configure this way. Other thing thats happens is when I install (sudo apt-get postfix) I'm getting fopen: permission denied... u know?

Comment: The correct command is `sudo apt-get install postfix` (look into the Server Guide). If you get an error with that command please post a new question.

Comment: oh.. sure... was that what i mean...

Comment: I just install CentOS 6 and do everything again. Now its working. Thanks!